# How to create and use a styled-component that renders {props.children} in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, styled-components

I have an `ExternalLink` component that I use to render anchor tags for external URLs. I've implemented it using `styled-components`.

[CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-chebyshev-spl5o)

**ExternalLink.tsx**

It basically gets an `href` prop and render the children as `{props.children}`.

```
const LinkAnchor = styled.a``;

interface ExternalLink_I {
  className?: string;
  href: string;
}

const ExternalLink: React.FC<ExternalLink_I> = (props) => {
  console.log("Rendering ExternalLink...");

  return (
    <LinkAnchor
      className={props.className} // ALLOW STYLING WITH STYLED-COMPONENTS
      href={props.href}
      target="_blank"
      rel="noopener noreferrer"
    >
      {props.children}
    </LinkAnchor>
  );
};
```

But I'm getting an error when rendering this component with children.

**App.tsx**

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <ExternalLink href={"https://www.google.com"}>
      EXTERNAL_LINK
    </ExternalLink>
  );
}
```

[image]

Here is the error msg in text format:

> Type '{ children: string; href: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ExternalLink_I'.
>
> Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ExternalLink_I'.ts(2322)

---

**QUESTION**

What am I doing wrong? How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to mention that the ExternalLink component was wrapped in React.memo. The 'children' prop has been known to cause issues with React.memo, hence removed from the type definitions for the component. Also looking at your code, doesn't seem to be making any big optimisations. Removing it would fix the type error, or you could choose to ignore it.

Here is some light reading regarding this issue:

- [Q: When should you NOT use React memo? #14463](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14463)
- [Why using the children prop makes React.memo() not work](https://gist.github.com/slikts/e224b924612d53c1b61f359cfb962c06)

Comment: Sorry. I did forget to mention that. I wrap everything in `React.memo()` these days. Do you think it might cause some trouble in this example?

Comment: It should technically work, but memo components are known to glitch out or stop working when given children prop. As I said, you could ignore it, as the CodeSandbox seems to be working fine, but better if you simply remove the memo as it won't make a difference in this use case. You could dive into the GitHub issue if you want to know more.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `children` type too:

```
interface ExternalLink_I {
  ...
  // or React.element, React.ReactNode etc
  children: string;
}
```